# Playing a m3u8 file to Exo Player

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I integrated Exoplayer v2 to my project because I wanted to play hls streams like m3u8, so I tried like this

```
protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PLAY);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,
                new DefaultTrackSelector());
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "asasas"));

        MediaSource mediaSource =
                new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

but still it can't play at all , in my debugger it says unable to connect to the stream , I am using exoplayer 2.8.4

Erros on log are here

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to https://myjsonresponselink
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:194)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:429)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:350)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:192)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:429) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:350) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:192) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339) 
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source:0) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:429) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:350) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:192) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:137) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:320) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

so how am i supposed to fix this, it is the first time i use exo player please help me

Comment: Could you share the whole log?

Comment: @MiguelIsla i edited anser, you can see the log

Comment: The problem seems to be related with your servers certificate's or with https. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection), it may solve your problem.

Comment: @MiguelIsla but when the file format is mp4 it starts playing , i only have problems with m3u8

Comment: Can you start playing your m3u8 with another program such VLC?

Comment: Also this [other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353248/exoplayer-player-video-mp4-e-stream-m3u8) could lead you to a solution.

Comment: @MiguelIsla yes i do and it works like charm, it is a wowza stream by the way

Comment: Thanks @MiguelIsla but it doesn't work , any other player suggestion, what to use for playing these streams, and free

Comment: Have you tried this with a different m3u8 file? Looks like a cert error like Miguel mentioned

Comment: @Nevermore yes now i tried and some of them work, only wowza https links doesnt work, how to fix this

Comment: Did u try using http instead? @Jack1999

Comment: @Nevermore i tried now but these links only work in https

Comment: @i played this with giraffe player, but why exo player doesn't allow me to play this

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3158) is related?

Comment: @MiguelIsla i found a solution but i dont know where to write it , I need to add this line somewhere  `httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(trustCert().getSocketFactory());`